# Black screen with 5.1.2 f1 & Cardboard v0.5.1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I just created a new, clean Unity project with Unity 5.1.2 f1 & Cardboard v0.5.1.

- DeviceID in Assets -> Plugins -> Android -> assets folder.
- VR disabled in Unity.
- VR Mode enabled in Cardboard main prefab.
- 1 Worldspace canvas with 1 button.

I get a **black screen** when launching a build on an Android Device running 4.4 (KitKat)

If I turn off "VR Mode Enabled" on the Cardboard Main prefab I get the VR scene but nothing is rendered.

Black screen does not occur with Cardboard 4.10 SDK for Unity.

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this?
p.s. Before the updates everything worked perfectly.

Thanks